# THE MORE constrained I expect to be, I plan to save MORE

Tags: grammaticality, parallelism

> 1. The more constrained I expect to be in the future, I plan to save more today

Is (1) above grammatically correct (parallelism)?

Alternatively, should it be the following?

> 2. The more constrained I expect to be in the future, the more I plan to save today

Would the structure posed in (1) violate parallelism?

Comment: No, but the sentence itself is not idiomatic or likely.

Comment: @KillingTime I meant it as in planning to adhere to a budget to a greater extent. However, I do see the ambiguity of "budget more" as it may be interpreted as a larger budget amount. To focus on grammaticality, I have modified the question.

Comment: The version in the *title* is non-idiomatic, but the alternative as given in the question *text* is fine.

Comment: [This question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3944/what-are-sentences-like-the-longer-x-the-more-y-called-and-can-they-be-used-i) is relevant, as it discusses the general construction "the more ... the more ..."

Comment: @StuartF Yes, that answer's a good summary. _The more ... the more_ is an idiomatic construction, and it requires that formulation before parallel constituents. So the first sentence is not the idiom and it's hard to parse because it's not parallel at all; it took me two tries to hear it as grammatical. As you suggest, the second one is preferable.

Comment: As @JohnLawler says, this is an idiomatic construction. Part of the reason that it's idiomatic is that the word *the* here has lost its original meaning. This construction used to be easier to understand  than it is now. The word *the* in this construction looks like the definite article *the*, but was originally a demonstrative quantifier meaning something like "that much." So *The more it rains, the more the grass grows* means something like "That much more that it rains, that much more the grass grows" or, to put it differently ... (continued)

Comment: "As much as it rains more, so much more the grass will grow." So a fundamental problem with your sentence is that it is missing the most important part of the idiom in the second clause. It is missing the key word *the*! Although its meaning is kind of lost in the modern language, it is still an important part of the idiom. Notice that this word *the* (not the definite article proper) turns up in other idiomatic constructions, such as *all the more*, and in folkloric fairy stories: *All **the** better to eat you with!*

Answer (score 1):

In a construction whose parallelism rests on a pairing of two phrases that include the wording "the more," this is the basic form that the parallelism takes:

> the more X, the more Y

where X and Y consist of similar constituents, such as single nouns:

> the more pain, the more gain

or noun-verb combinations:

> the more you argue, the more I disagree

or complex phrases:

> the more vigorously the rabbit struggled to free itself, the more firmly it got stuck to the tar baby

If we try to reduce the sentence proposed in the title—"The more constrained I expect to be in the future, I plan to save more today"—to a simplified "the more X, the more Y" form, however, we can't do it. In fact, the closest reduction we can get to it is something like this:

> the more X, Y more

That isn't a parallel construction; it's just a sentence that uses "more" in both of its main phrases. Actually , there is a hint of parallelism in the construction, but it comes in the positioning of the temporal elements "in the future" and "today" at the end of the two main phrases. So we could claim that there is parallelism of the following form:

> X in the future, Y today

But when people talk about parallel constructions, they generally have in mind something structurally more significant than parallel tails.

It's important to recognize that parallelism isn't some sort of binary on/off quality that a construction either has or doesn't have. It can exist in varying degrees in a sentence, from word-for-word structural matching to the almost trivial level of parallelism involved in the "X in the future, Y today" construction above.

The sentence proposed in the body of the question—"The more constrained I expect to be in the future, the more I plan to save today"—achieves much greater structural parallelism than the sentence in the question title does, because it meets the threshold of satisfying "the more X, the more Y" form. Even so, the X and Y branches of the construction aren't really built to the same pattern. To increase the degree of parallelism in the sentence, we'd have to adjust either the X branch or the Y branch to more closely match the form of its partner. You could change the X branch to follow the pattern of the Y branch more closely:

> The more I expect to be constrained in the future, the more I plan to save today.

or you could change the Y branch to follow the pattern of the X branch more closely:

> The more constrained I expect to be in the future, the more motivated I am to plan to save today.

Increasing the parallelism of the construction is useful in a way that you might not have expected: it reveals an ambiguity in the original assertion that you can now take steps to resolve. The ambiguity involves whether you mean to say that expecting greater economic constraints in the future leads to more planning to save money today or whether it leads to planning to save more money today. That is, are you trying to say:

> The more severe the economic constraints are that I expect to experience in the future, the more motivated I am to plan to save money today.

or are you trying to say

> The more severe the economic constraints are that I expect to experience in the future, the more money I plan to save today.

These assertions may look similar, but in terms of the underlying "more" comparison, they are quite different. One involves matching constraints to planning ("the more constraints, the more planning"), and the other involves matching constraints to money ("the more constraints, the more money"). Once you resolve which of the two meanings you want to convey, you can try to frame aparallel construction that captures that meaning accurately. For example:

> The more severely I expect to be constrained economically in the future, the more urgently I feel the need to make plans to save money today.

or:

> The more economically constrained I expect to be in the future, the more money I plan to save from now on.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore: Thank you for your helpful suggestion. I have tried to capture the essence of your recommendation without repeating the word "phrase" in the opening sentence of my answer (for aesthetic reasons).